# httpclient cancellation token only works for 21 seconds or less

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation-token

I'm using `httpclient` with it's default `timeout` (`100 seconds`). But it seems it's not obeying the default `100 seconds` nor `cancellation token timeout` passed.
If I set anything less than 22 seconds in my cancellation token, then that's when cancellation kicks in.

```
var time = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
try
{
    var sourceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    CancellationTokenSource source= new CancellationTokenSource(sourceTimeout);        

    timer.Restart();
    var r = await _httpClient.GetAsync(requestUri, source.Token);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    time.Stop();
    var elapsed = time.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Actual results:

```
sourceTimeout: 5minutes
ex: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException. Inner ex: System.Net.Http.WinRequestException
message: An error occurred while sending the request.
inner ex message: The operation timed out
elapsed: 21.1632636

sourceTimeout: 30seconds
ex: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException. Inner ex: System.Net.Http.WinRequestException
message: An error occurred while sending the request.
inner ex message: The operation timed out
elapsed: 21.145141799999998

sourceTimeout: 20seconds
ex: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
message: A task was canceled.
elapsed: 20.0714319

sourceTimeout: 10seconds
ex: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
message: A task was canceled.
elapsed: 10.0688566
```

The `HttpClient` default timeout settings reports `00:01:40` or rather `100 seconds`.

Where does this `21-ish` seconds come from whenever my timeout settings is more than 21 seconds?

Comment: What is the exception you get? Are you sure it is a timeout exception?

Comment: which case are you referring to @Magnus? I have 2 cases above. when I set cancellation timeout to anything above 21 seconds, and when I set it to anything below 21 seconds.

Comment: Above 21 seconds

Comment: @Magnus I edited the question and gave as much detail as I can get. Hope that answers your question.